# How to creat index and search query in Java Lucene 6.2.0

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I want to use Lucene version 6.2.0, I created two functions in java is creatIndex and searchIndex but it doesn't run. I don't understand how to use Field to argument of Documents methods.

```
public void searchIndex(String sentence) throws IOException
{
    File dir = new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
    Path path = dir.toPath();
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
    DirectoryReader ireader=DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    IndexSearcher isearcher=new IndexSearcher(ireader);
    PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder(); 
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        builder.add(new Term("contents", word));
    }
    PhraseQuery pq = builder.build();
    TopDocs topDocs = isearcher.search(pq, 10);
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = isearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

Comment: It not run and this is errors :  at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.<init>(Field.java:249)
at study_lucense.Study_Lucense.creatDocument(Study_Lucense.java:55)
at study_lucense.Study_Lucense.main(Study_Lucense.java:86)

Comment: It is more helpful if you add the error, including what *kind of exception* is being thrown, into the question, rather than as a comment.  There should be an "edit" link at the bottom of the question, which would allow you to add that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems strike me here:

1. Your `creatDocuments` opens an index in the same place it's looking for files to index, at the `Files` argument.  Your `searchIndex` method is then looking for the index at `INDEX_DIRECTORY`.  I presume your `creatDocuments` should be opening a writer at `INDEX_DIRECTORY` as well.  Like

   ```
   FSDirectory luceneDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY).toPath());
   IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig();
   try (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, conf)) {
       for (File file : new File(Files).listFiles()) {
       ...
   ```
2. Your `FieldType` won't work.  You need to *at the very least* specify that it is either indexed or stored.  I would recommend you don't start with custom field types.  Just use the `Field` implementations with pre-defined field types, like `TextField` (see the list of "Direct Known Subclasses" in the [Field documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html)).

   ```
       Field contentField = new TextField(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, reader);
       Field fileNameField = new TextField(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME, file.getName(), Field.Store.YES);
       Field filePathField = new TextField(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH, file.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.NO);
   ```
3. You are reusing the same `Document`, rather than creating a new ones for each file.  You should be constructing a new `Document` for each iteration of your for loop.

Comment: 2 . if I don't use FieldType , it's error . I'm using Lucene version 6.2.0 . It don't suitable with Field constructor .

Comment: @drag - That's why I recommended using `TextField` instead.  If you use `Field`, then yes, you'll need to generate a `FieldType`, specifying exactly how the field should be indexed.